# Tomcat trying to resolve JSP files in RESTful Spring MVC Service

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jsp, tomcat

I am using Spring MVC to create a RESTful service, using the @Controller and @RequestMapping annotations to control responses. I am also using Maven as a dependency management system.

In one function, I use a URI template in my @RequestMapping to retrieve a variable from the GET request. This function returns JSON when it is complete.

Due to problems with the JSTL libraries as a result of using URI templates (essentially I was getting 500 status codes because of a ClassNotFoundException with a JSTL class), I had to add the following dependencies to my Maven POM file (these come from our private repository, but you should be able to understand what they are):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.2-rev-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

However, as a result of adding these, I now get 404 errors, because Tomcat (which is handling the requests under Spring) is trying to resolve my URI, which is usually

localhost:9095/DiagnosticToolService/demo-object/1/json (the 1 being my GET variable, of course)

to a file, specifically

localhost:9095/DiagnosticToolService/WEB-INF/jsp/demo-object/1/json.jsp

Of course, this file does not exist. How do I turn off this automatic JSP resolution in Tomcat so that it can work properly? Also, are those the dependencies I needed to add to fix the 500 error? The 500 error and the 404 error are shown below:

[image: 500 error]

The 500 error

[image: 404 error]

The 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using @ResponseBody on your controller method that produces JSON? from the description of the problem it looks like the request is not making it to your controller or the return value from the controller is interpreted as a view name.

Can you post the mapping you are using on the controller just the method signature?